# Git: Getting total numbers of uncomitted lines in a repo

Tags: git, bash, zsh

Is there a command to get just total number of **lines** that are changed in current git repo. I want to take count **considering both staged and unstaged** files.

This is the closest I could get

```
$ git diff --cached --shortstat
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git diff --shortstat
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

But I have to execute two commands and then parse (quite error prone, you never know all cases) result to find number of **lines** that have changed.

If not a git command, a bash/zsh function would also do.

**UPDATE:**

So the idea was to track total uncommitted lines (showing approximate level of dirtiness of a git working directory) on my ZSH prompt, Something like:

```
[~/dotfiles] (master) ✗ [192]
$ ...
```

So thanks to @arco444's answer, which I slightly modified, I now have following, just if someone wants to achieve the same

```
function git_change_count {
    local IS_INSIDE_REPO=$(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null)
    if [[ $IS_INSIDE_REPO == "true" ]]; then
        { git diff --cached --numstat; git diff --numstat; } | awk '{ a+=($1+$2) } END {print a}'
    fi
}
```

I am adding the lines that were added and deleted lines, instead of getting their diff. Which essentially means edited lines shows up as 2 but doing so covers the scenario when two different lines were added and deleted and because of subtraction we get 0 as result.

Comment: Those two commands will double-count lines that have changed in both locations. This seems like a strange thing to want to do to me. What's the ultimate goal here?

Comment: @EtanReisner The idea is capture 'dirtiness' of given git working directory. It does not have to be precise. I'm okay if a line, that is staged is counted twice if it is changed again in unstaged version.

Comment: @kunal I like this, how did you add the function to show in the prompt top line?

Comment: @Ziv just call the function in the prompt variable like `PROMPT='....$(git_change_count)...'`. New lines in `PROMPT` string are preserved and so you get new line on prompt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
{ git diff --cached --numstat; git diff --numstat; } | awk '{ a+=($1-$2) } END {print a}'
```

The `--numstat` flag gives you:

```
#added #deleted #filename
```

You need to run it for both staged and unstaged files, then pipe to `awk` to do the arithmetic. It will return a sum of added and deleted lines, so you will get a negative result if more lines were removed than added.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
git diff --numstat |  cut -d$'\t' -f 1 | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

Here the `git diff --numstat` provides the number of additions and substractions for each file (separated by tabs). The `cut` command splits the fields by tabs, selecting the first field (additions). The `paste` command creates an addition from the column of numbers and the `bc` command performs the sum. The above is for additions. You can do subtraction by replacing the `-f 1` with `-f 2`. If you want additions and subtractions, try:

```
git diff --numstat |  cut -d$'\t' -f 1,2 | tr '\t' '+' | paste -sd+ -  | bc
```

which just uses `tr` to insert addition signs on every row before using `paste`