# File Specific Report generator

Tags: git, svn, jenkins, gitlab

Can anyone point me in right direction, I'm looking for a tool that can give a report with new lines or modified lines of code added to a project. We are working with SVN, ant, maven, gradel, jenkins, sonar, fisheye, crucible. My boss wants us to generate a report on weekly basis that shows how many new or modified lines of code is added to a project. Please help me out with any tool or script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`git diff --numstat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9933440/6309) can easily do that for a all repo between two dates.
See also "[`git diff --stat` explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25541864/6309)"

```
git diff --numstat "@{7 day ago}"
```

You would need to [parse its output to get the total](https://gist.github.com/robskillington/776e6a7e34863848ede8), as in "[Git: Getting total numbers of uncomitted lines in a repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33544837/6309)".
More [complete tools are listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/882160/6309).

For SVN, see "[How many lines of code modified during a time period?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1538143/6309)", or "[What svn command would list all the files modified on a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/160370/6309)".

Comment: Hey @VonC , currently we are using svn also. Is there any process for SVN?